# Custom spacing in aligned environment

Tags: spacing, environments, align

How can I add an arbitrary horizontal spacing in an aligned environment? \hspace{} and \qquad don't work.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}               %Zeichencodierung Text
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                     %Schriftsatz Dokument


%%Language settings
\usepackage[english]{babel}                  %ngerman for German
\usepackage{csquotes}                        %[babel,quotes=english]
\usepackage{caption}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}}
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}   % only works when not using babel


%%Math, astro, chemical packages and options
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{wasysym}                        %astronomical symbols
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}             %Chemie-Package
\providecommand{\e}[1]{\ensuremath{\times 10^{#1}}}

%\usepackage{dsfont}
%\usepackage{enumerate,url}


%%Paper adjustments
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}                        %if problems with importing .eps graphics
%\usepackage{a4wide}                         %obsolete and replaced by geometry
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom=3.1cm]{geometry}  %also with command \geometry{options}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
%\usepackage{subfigure}                      %obsolete
%\usepackage{subcaption}                      %cannot be used with subfigure
\usepackage{subfig}
%\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{textcomp, gensymb}               %textcomp before gensymb gets rid of the warnings "not defining \micro and \perthousand
\usepackage{soul}                            %for customised working with the text 
\usepackage{array}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}                  %sets the section number depth
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}                     %sets the ToC depth
%\usepackage{verbatim}                       %for multiline comments using \begin{} or \end{comment}
\usepackage{xcolor}                          %colour e.g. parts of equations

%% Control the fonts and formatting used in the table of contents.
%\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

%% Aesthetic spacing redefined
%\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{}
%\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}                  %kein Einrücken von neuen Abschnitten
\usepackage{afterpage}                       %to avoid space before landscape-environment



\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
{}^{16}_{\phantom{0}8}O^{}_{8} + n \rightarrow
{}^{15}_{\phantom{0}8}O^{}_{7} + 2n
\\
{\hspace{17.5mm} \searrow} {}^{15}_{\phantom{0}7}N^{*}_{8} + {e}^{+} + \nu
\\
{\hspace{38.5mm} \searrow} {}^{15}_{\phantom{0}7}N^{}_{8} + \gamma
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at the `mhchem` package. And remember an MWE is *minimal*, many of those packages are not related to your question.

Comment: The first field of `aligned` is right-aligned, so add a `&` to the beginning of each row (since the 2nd field of `aligned` is left aligned).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "field"?

Comment: With `aligned` type environments, rows are expected to have the field separator `&` in them.  Everything before the `&` in each row is right aligned, and everything after the `&` in each row is left aligned.  See the FOLLOW-UP section of my answer.

Comment: I had those `&`, too. But as they were shown to me as errors I replaced them with `\hspace{}`.

Answer (score 1):

The first field of `aligned` is right-aligned, so add a `&` to the beginning of each row (since the 2nd field of `aligned` is left aligned).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}               %Zeichencodierung Text
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                     %Schriftsatz Dokument


%%Language settings
\usepackage[english]{babel}                  %ngerman for German
\usepackage{csquotes}                        %[babel,quotes=english]
\usepackage{caption}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}}
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}   % only works when not using babel


%%Math, astro, chemical packages and options
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{wasysym}                        %astronomical symbols
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}             %Chemie-Package
\providecommand{\e}[1]{\ensuremath{\times 10^{#1}}}

%\usepackage{dsfont}
%\usepackage{enumerate,url}


%%Paper adjustments
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}                        %if problems with importing .eps graphics
%\usepackage{a4wide}                         %obsolete and replaced by geometry
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom=3.1cm]{geometry}  %also with command \geometry{options}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
%\usepackage{subfigure}                      %obsolete
%\usepackage{subcaption}                      %cannot be used with subfigure
\usepackage{subfig}
%\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{textcomp, gensymb}               %textcomp before gensymb gets rid of the warnings "not defining \micro and \perthousand
\usepackage{soul}                            %for customised working with the text 
\usepackage{array}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}                  %sets the section number depth
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}                     %sets the ToC depth
%\usepackage{verbatim}                       %for multiline comments using \begin{} or \end{comment}
\usepackage{xcolor}                          %colour e.g. parts of equations

%% Control the fonts and formatting used in the table of contents.
%\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

%% Aesthetic spacing redefined
%\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{}
%\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}                  %kein Einrücken von neuen Abschnitten
\usepackage{afterpage}                       %to avoid space before landscape-environment



\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&{}^{16}_{\phantom{0}8}O^{}_{8} + n \rightarrow
{}^{15}_{\phantom{0}8}O^{}_{7} + 2n
\\
&{\hspace{17.5mm} \searrow} {}^{15}_{\phantom{0}7}N^{*}_{8} + {e}^{+} + \nu
\\
&{\hspace{38.5mm} \searrow} {}^{15}_{\phantom{0}7}N^{}_{8} + \gamma
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your goal is to achieve left alignment, dispense with the `\hspace` and just use the field separators:

```
\begin{aligned}
&{}^{16}_{\phantom{0}8}O^{}_{8} + n \rightarrow
{}^{15}_{\phantom{0}8}O^{}_{7} + 2n
\\
&\searrow {}^{15}_{\phantom{0}7}N^{*}_{8} + {e}^{+} + \nu
\\
&\searrow {}^{15}_{\phantom{0}7}N^{}_{8} + \gamma
\end{aligned}
```

[image]

---

FOLLOW UP:

To help the OP understand what `aligned` does, I provide this example to demonstrate how the first field (prior to `&`) becomes right-aligned and the second field (following `&`) is left aligned (while accounting for the `\hspace`).

```
\begin{aligned}
xxx&{}^{16}_{\phantom{0}8}O^{}_{8} + n \rightarrow
{}^{15}_{\phantom{0}8}O^{}_{7} + 2n
\\
yy&{\hspace{17.5mm} \searrow} {}^{15}_{\phantom{0}7}N^{*}_{8} + {e}^{+} + \nu
\\
z&{\hspace{38.5mm} \searrow} {}^{15}_{\phantom{0}7}N^{}_{8} + \gamma
\end{aligned}
```

[image]

Based on the OP's comment, perhaps he is confused by syntax highlighting:

[image]

In this case, different colors do not imply error (necessarily), but rather are visual aids to typing good code.  I would expect things like `&` to be highlighted by a good editor (as seen in TeXworks above).

Comment: TexStudio shows me those `&`red in my syntax but does not create an error. It says this table command is outside of a table environment.

Comment: @Lucas I don't use TeXStudio.  However, many editors show different syntax is highlighted colors, not to point out errors, but to make it easier to visually digest.  See my revision.

Comment: @Lucas In the code you have provided, there is no `table` environment shown.

Comment: @Steben B. Segletes Exactly. So using a `&` in an aligned environment requires a table package or to put the whole \begin+\end{aligned} in a \begin+\end{table} or tabular? Or even the whole equation environment?

Comment: @Lucas  No.  `table` and `aligned` are mutually exclusive environments.  I get no such warnings/errors when I compile the code.  Perhaps delete the .aux file and recompile my example to see if the error goes away.

Comment: The red marking behind `&` is still there, so also the comment that this table command is outside of a table environment. I could leave it like this, as no error is shown and the pdf looks as I want it.